# Debian 9.2 Expert mode Login problem

Tags: linux, debian, password, root

I just install Debian 9.2 (expert mode) and I only allow root login I didn't add new user , so my problem was into getting in the system with root login and password which didn't work ( I'm sure 100% of my login password) .

I really want to use Debian as expert mode I don't want to write user pass every time i want to do something in the system , because I always use Kali as a primary OS but now I want to use Debian as my priamry OS.

Comment: Well, I highly doubt you cannot login to the server with the correct root password, unless of course you are trying to login via `ssh` and root login is disabled. And please capitalize your I's.

Comment: i'm sure that root login are enabled

Comment: How are you trying to login to the server? `ssh` or locally? If it is `ssh` root login is disabled by default

Comment: i am trying to login to debian locally  , i write root and my password and it don't work

Comment: Try resetting your root password with the answer below. I don't believe there is anything else that could be blocking you from logging in right after installation with the correct root password.

Comment: Your desire to avoid entering your password to access administrative tools is _nothing whatsoever_ to do with "expert mode" installation. I'd suggest you go back and perform a normal installation and then come and search here for answers relating to entering passwords to get to root (see the keyword `sudo`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're system has somehow messed up the root password. Try resetting the root password. Use the following steps to reset root password

1. Edit the grub command line during boot by pressing `e`.
2. Scroll down to end of the grub line by pressing `Down Arrow` and `Right Arrow`
3. Add a `space` followed by `init=/bin/bash`
4. Press `Ctrl+X` to boot the edited command line.
5. Remount the file system in read and write mode `mount -rw -o remount /`
6. Change root password with `passwd` command. **Chose a simple Number only password. Don't use Numpad** to type password. Otherwise due to keyboard mapping issue unwanted password may be typed.
7. Reboot with `reboot` command.

Now try login to your system with new root password. Hope this will solve the situation